# Custom implementation of systemcall with undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, c, assembly, linux-kernel, inline-assembly

I'm trying to implement my own version of a systemcall wrapper for x86_64/gcc for linux. The code does work when compiled with -O0 or the **attribute** ((noinline)) like in the listing. However if inlining is allowed the code breaks (segfault) in optimized builds. Because the error only happens in optimized builds the debugger is not too helpful, but right after the systemcall some variables are changed, that should not be touched by the systemcall. There is probably undefined behavior involved in how I setup the ASM code.

```
auto __attribute__ ((noinline)) systemcall(int id, auto rdi, auto rsi, auto rdx, auto _r10, auto _r8, auto _r9) {
    int64_t err_code = 0;
    register auto r10 asm("r10") = _r10;
    register auto r8 asm("r8") = _r8;
    register auto r9 asm("r9") = _r9;
    asm volatile (
        "syscall"
        : "=a" (err_code)
        : "a" (id), "D" (rdi), "S" (rsi), "d" (rdx), "r"(r10), "r"(r8), "r"(r9)
        : "memory"
    );
    return err_code;
}
```

Comment: Also mention what is your question.

Comment: C or C++? Pick one. (This doesn't look like C to me)

Comment: System calls trash `rcx`.  Add it to your clobber list.

Comment: @fuz thanks for the solution. If you make it an answer I'll accept it to mark the thread as anwered. I double checked and R11 need to be clobbered too.

Comment: @OutOfBound dupe'd it instead